# service for restoring tapes

Tags: restore, backupexec, service, tape

I've got 30 to 40 LTO-1 and LTO-2 tapes that we used with BackupExec to backup our data. About a year ago we moved to another backup solution (Veeam).

My LTO drive is dying/dead, and I'd like to restore the data from these tapes, probably to a hard drive.

I don't really want to buy a new LTO drive (or roll the dice with a used one from ebay) to do this restore.

Can anyone recommend a service that could do this for me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any data-recovery service should be well-equipped to perform this work for you. BackupExec is pretty standard and since there's no deep-forensics involved, this should be straightforward. Ideally, you could provide hard drives for them to restore to, but they can furnish them as well. Get a few quotes before you jump in.

http://services.seagate.com/tape_data_recovery.aspx

http://www.krollontrack.com/data-recovery/tape-restoration-services/

http://www.datarecoverysouth.com/tape-data-recovery.html

Comment: +1 - Assuming the tapes are undamaged this should be relatively inexpensive (to whatever extent that data recovery places are *ever* inexpensive - probably cheaper than a new tape drive though...)